# Not able to select the latest row with maximum date

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: 1]DB table structure above

[image: 2] Result

See the images

```
SELECT max(comment_date), comment_content FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_post_id = 8687
```

It selects the field with latest date but wrong content.

I want to implement this in the below query which already has one GROUP BY statement and multiple JOINS, using limit alters the result.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should fail, because it is an aggregation query and it has no `group by` but has unaggregated columns.

The simple way to do this uses `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM wp_comments c
WHERE comment_post_id = 8687
ORDER BY comment_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select max date in sub query and fetch required columns.

```
SELECT comment_date, comment_content
FROM wp_comments 
WHERE comment_post_id = 8687
AND comment_date = (Select max(b.comment_date) from
wp_comment b)
```

Answer (score 0):

use a Join with the same table with the max date and searching for the coincidence

```
SELECT comment_date, comment_content 
FROM wp_comments a
JOIN (SELECT comment_post_id, max(comment_date) as maxdate FROM wp_comments) b ON 
b.comment_post_id = a.comment_post_id 
and b.maxdate = a.comment_date 
WHERE comment_post_id = 8687
```